# Is it feasible to use "provided that" in second conditionals or third conditionals?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, writing

I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know whether it is feasible to use "provided that" or "providing that" with third or second conditional statements. I mean, is it appropriate to write sentences as the following ones.

If she passed the exam, she could apply to the university. But she does not work much these days.

**Provided that she passed the exam, she could apply for the university.**

If she had worked hard, she could have passed the exam. But she couldn't achieve that as she didn't work hard.

**Provided that she had worked hard, she could have passed the exam.**